# How to configure Heroku's Facebook tutorial app to run locally with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

I am trying to run the Heroku's basic tutorial facebook application (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook).
Following the instructions, deploying on Heroku went fine.
Trying to deploy locally I got the following error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\AppInfo.php on line 36".

I understood there's some problem with the getHome function, found an answer to a similar problem with python here - [Problem running Heroku's Facebook app tutorial with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541469/problem-running-herokus-facebook-app-tutorial-with-python), but still I am unable to figure it out how it should be done for PHP.

I tried to changed the getHome function to just `return http://127.0.0.1:5000/` (like the Site URL I set on my facebook app) but then I get that the browser cannot connect to it.

I have Safari 2.2 running locally, basic Hello world PHP file is running ok.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the contents of AppInfo.php? atleast the relative part of the code of line #36

Comment: `return ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ?: "http") . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your comment what you do there is wrong. It should be

```
return ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ?: "http:" . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
```

Comment: Same error Tjirp. Working locally I do not think I need this code anyway, but just to hard code something. As I wrote above, I tried `return http://127.0.0.1:5000/` but the browser is refusing to go there. It is able to go to http://127.0.0.1, anything special I need to do to make it work with 5000?

Answer (score 0):

The app is relying on a PHP 5.3 operator to do an "or equals" on that line. It works like this:

```
$foo ?: "bar";
```

Which means: assume the value of $foo if set, otherwise "bar". To make that compatible with earlier versions of PHP you'd have to rewrite it using a different operator and functions. Like:

```
isset($foo) ? $foo : "bar";
```

So going back to the app, you can fix it with:

```
$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] : "http";
return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/";
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362626/php-equivalent-for-rubys-or-equals-foo-bar) has more information on PHP's or equals and alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, Pedro. This probably fixed the PHP part of the problem and made it worked instead of using the hardcoded return statement I stated above. However, I am still getting the same error when trying to load the Facebook application. Guess, it is something with the application/Apache settings.